# Uniqueness of probability given marginals

Tags: matrices, probability-distributions

Let $X,Y,Z$  be finite sets, and consider probability distributions $p$ over $X\times Y\times Z$. If we know the marginals of $p$ over all the pairs $X\times Y$, $X\times Z$ and $Y\times Z$, is that enough to pin down $p$ uniquely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider $X=Y=Z=\{0,1\}$ and the following two probability distributions:

- $p_1(x,y,z) = \frac18$
- $p_2(x,y,z) = \frac18\left(1 + (-1)^{x+y+z}\right)$

It is easily checked that in both cases, all marginal distributions are equally distributed.

Answer (score 0):

No, marginals never give you the joint distribution. For a simpler case, take $p$ uniformly distributed on $[0,1]^2$ and $q$ uniformly distributed on the diagonal line segment $\{(x,y) : x = y, 0 \leq x \leq 1\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Both have both marginals being uniform on $[0,1]$ but $p$ and $q$ are distinct.